# website adjustment in screen res fitting

Tags: javascript, html, css

hi im new  here in creating a website. I really cant figure out it how can I make an auto adjustment of my website were it could fit on different screen resolution and also when the window is resized to much smaller without overlaps of the content of the website?
right now my screen resolution is 1680 x 1050, where I actually creating the website .

hope you can help me. thanks!

Comment: You should check responsive via media queries

Answer (score 1):

You most likely need to use what are called `media queries`:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 975px){
    body{...}
    div{...}
}
```

Read up on them at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)